# Not Display Product Name in the Email template?

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, email-templates

> module.xml
>
> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
>     <module name="Magetrend_Custom" schema_version="2.0.0" setup_version="2.0.0">
>         <sequence>
>             <module name="Magetrend_Email"/>
>         </sequence>
>     </module>
> </config>
> ```

registration.php

```
 <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magetrend_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

event file C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\app\code\Magetrend\Custom\etc events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="magetrend_email_collect_additional_vars">
        <observer name="mtemail_custom_var" instance="Magetrend\Custom\Observer\CustomVar"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

observer file C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\app\code\Magetrend\Custom\Observer CustomVar.php

```
<?php
```

namespace Magetrend\Custom\Observer;

class CustomVar implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
protected $order;

```
public function __construct(           
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order  
)
{ 
    $this->order = $order;
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{       
    $transport = $observer->getTransport();
    $orderId = $observer->getTransport()->getOrderId();
    $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
    $allVisibleItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $totalItemsCount = count($order->getAllVisibleItems());
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($allVisibleItems as $item)
    {
        if($i == 0){
            $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if($totalItemsCount > 1){
        $remainingItems = $totalItemsCount - 1;
        $transport['itemName'] = $productName.' and '.$remainingItems .' more products'; 
    }else{
        $transport['itemName'] = $productName;   
    }
}
```

}

[image]
[image: gmail picture]

---

what is the problem? email template

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the email_order_set_template_vars_before event, which allows you to send custom parameters to your order email. Check the working code below:**

**app/code/Magetrend/Custom/etc**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
     <observer name="mtemail_custom_var" instance="Magetrend\Custom\Observer\CustomVar"/>
 </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Magetrend/Custom/Observer**

**CustomVar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Magetrend\Custom\Observer;

class CustomVar implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    )
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $orderId = $observer->getTransport()->getOrderId();
        $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
        $allVisibleItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $totalItemsCount = count($order->getAllVisibleItems());
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($allVisibleItems as $item)
        {
            if($i == 0){
                $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if($totalItemsCount > 1){
            $remainingItems = $totalItemsCount - 1;
            $transport['itemName'] = $productName.' and '.$remainingItems .' more products';
        }else{
            $transport['itemName'] = $productName;
        }
    }
}
```

> **Add the following line to the email template:**

```
<h3>{{var itemName|raw}}</h3>
```

**Note: After updating and adding the above code, please revise your order email template. Ensure that you are checking the correct order email template. Add a static value and verify if the order email is displaying correctly or not.**